# Compaq Presario CQ40 Hardware Problem

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, laptop-repair, laptop-display

i have this Compaq Presario CQ40 Laptop and when i turned on the machine, it shows no display, it seems no interaction with the monitor. And there's a led that continuously blinking 4 times then pause then 4 times then pause..

any help please..

what would be the problem on my laptop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong with your graphics card / subsystem:

[HP Support Blank Screen Error Code](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01443366&product=3752104)